# Minecraft Chest Placement

Tags: code-golf

The video game [Minecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) is all about placing and removing different types of blocks in the 3D [integer lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_lattice) that makes up the virtual world. Each lattice point can contain exactly one block or be empty (an "[air](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Air)" block officially). In this challenge, we will only be concerned with one horizontal 2D plane of the 3D world, and one type of block: [chests](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chest).

Chests let players store items. When two chests are orthogonally adjacent in the same horizontal plane, their textures link up and a double chest with twice the capacity forms. Nothing bigger than a double chest can be made; there are no triple chests nor quadruple chests.

A chest block can only be placed in an empty lattice point if its four orthogonally adjacent points are all empty, or if exactly one contains a chest block that is not already part of a double chest. These placement rules ensure that there can never be any ambiguity about which chest blocks link to form double chests.

For example, suppose `.` is empty space and `C` is a chest: (The numbers are also empty space and just for identification purposes.)

```
.......C..
.1.C2.C3..
........5C
.CC4..CC..
..........
```

- A chest can be placed in spot 1 because its 4 neighbors are empty.
- A chest can be placed in spot 2 because the neighboring chest is not (yet) part of a double chest.
- A chest can't be put in spot 3 because there would be ambiguity over how the double chest forms.
- A chest can't be placed in spot 4 because the neighboring chest is already part of a double chest.
- A chest can be placed in spot 5. The diagonally neighboring double chest doesn't affect anything.

Assuming the area beyond the grid is empty, changing every `.` in the grid to a `*` if a chest could be placed there results in this:

```
******.C**
***C**C.**
*..***..*C
.CC.*.CC.*
*..***..**
```

Not all of the `*` spaces can be occupied with chests at the same time of course, but if you only had one chest, it could be placed in any of them.

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a `.` and `C` grid, and changes every `.` to a `*` if a chest could be placed there, printing or returning the resulting grid.

- Input can be from stdin or a file or as a string argument to a function.
- You may assume the input is well formed - i.e. a perfectly rectangular grid of text, at least 1 character wide and tall, only containing `.` and `C` You may optionally assume there is a trailing newline after the last row (and there may be one in the output).
- You may assume the arrangement of chests in the input is consistent with the rules above. There will never be ambiguities about which chests form double chests.
- If desired, you may use any three distinct [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters in place of `.`, `C`, and `*`. You may not use something else in place of newlines.
- All the chests are normal chests. Not [trapped chests](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Trapped_Chest) or [ender chests](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ender_Chest).

## Scoring

The submission with the [fewest bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins.

<sup>*For a Minecraft related challenge that's a bit more challenging, try [Nether Portal Detection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45488/26997).*</sup>

Comment: From a Minecrafting point of view, I found this pretty annoying in-game. Good thing there are trapped chests :P

Comment: When taking grid input from stdin or a single string argument, is it acceptable to take the grid dimensions as an additional input? or does it have to be inferred from newlines and string length?

Comment: @steveverrill It has to be inferred.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does every answer including my own have one downvote? I can only assume it is the same person, would they care to explain?

Comment: For an extra challenge, one could write a program to find the optimal placement for the chests; that is, find a configuration that allows the maximum number of additional chests to be placed without breaking the rules even between the new chests.

Comment: "If desired, you may use any three distinct printable ASCII characters in place of `.`, `C`, and `*`." -- Is that for input, output or both?

Comment: You can now place chests everywhere from 1.13

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CJam, <s>82 76 66 62 58</s> 54 bytes

```
qN/::~4{[8_]f/[9_]f*z{[{1$8-g)+}*]W%}%}*{_8<\2<8?}f%N*
```

Input format expects `0` for air cell and `8` for a chest cell. Output contains `1` for all cells that can be placed with a Chest.

*UPDATE* : <s>Fixed a bug. Increased by 3 bytes :(</s> golfed further :) . 4 bytes saved thanks to @Sp3000

Example input:

```
0000000800
0008008000
0000000008
0880008808
0000000000
```

Output:

```
1111110811
1110018010
1008800108
0880088008
1008800110
```

I think I am done golfing for now...

**Explanation**

```
qN/::~                   "This part converts the input into array of integer array";
qN/                      "Split input on new line";
   ::~                   "Parse each character in each row as integer";

4{[8_]f/[9_]f*z{[{1$8-g)+}*]W%}%}*

4{   ...z{       W%}%}*  "Run the logic 4 times, first, columns in correct order, then,";
                         "columns in reverse order, then for rows";
  [8_]f/[9_]f*           "Convert adjacent chests represented by two 8 into two 9";
                         "This happens for all the rows in the columns iterations and";
                         "for all the columns in the rows iterations";
  {               }%     "For each row/column";
   [{        }*]         "Reduce and wrap it back in the array";
     :I8-                "Store the second number in I, remove 8 from it";
         g               "Do signum. Now we have -1 for < 8 number, 0 for 8 and 1 for > 8";
          )+I            "Increment to get 0, 1 & 2. Add it to first number and put I back";

{_8<\2<8?}f%N*           "This part converts the output from previous iterations";
                         "to 3 character based final output and prints it";
{        }f%             "Map each row using the code block";
 _8<   8?                "If the value is greater than 7, make it 8, else:";
    \2<                  "If the value is greater than 1, make it 0, else 1";
            N*           "Join the arrays using new line";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%3A%3A~4%7B%5B8_%5Df%2F%5B9_%5Df*z%7B%5B%7B1%248-g)%2B%7D*%5DW%25%7D%25%7D*%7B_8%3C%5C2%3C8%3F%7Df%25N*&input=0000000800%0A0000008000%0A0008800008%0A0880088008%0A0008800000)

Answer (score 8):

## .NET Regex ([Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina)), <s>434</s> <s>416</s> 310 + 1 = 311 bytes

After the last challenge I answered in regex (the Nether Portal Challenge linked to in this challenge), I finally set out to write a command-line tool, which acts as an interpreter for .NET-style regular expressions, so I can answer questions with regex without being challenged that they're not a stand-alone language. I've named it Retina.

Now, this challenge doesn't lend itself very well to a regex submission, but I just had to use Retina now. ;) (Plus, Sp3000 challenged me to do so in chat.) So here it is:

**Regex file**

```
m`(?<=(?=.(.)*).*)(?<=((?<=(?<2>C|C(?(1)!)(\n|(?<-1>.))*)?)C(?=(?<2>C|(\n|(?<-1>.))*(?(1)!)C)?)(()(?(6)!)|(?<=^(?(7)!)(?<-7>.)*C).*\n(.)*()(?(8)!)))?){2}_(?=(?<2>((?(10)!)()|(?(11)!)()(.)*\n.*(?=C(?<-12>.)*(?(12)!)$))(?<=(?<2>C|C(?(1)!)(\n|(?<-1>.))*)?)C(?=(?<2>C|(\n|(?<-1>.))*(?(1)!)C)?))?){2}(?<-2>)?(?(2)!)
```

**Replacement file**

```
*
```

The regex file is mostly just the regex, except that `` ` `` lets you put a few options in the file, in this case simply multiline mode. When given two files, Retina automatically assumes replace-all mode. These two files define a program which reads the input from STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT.

You can also test it on [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=e62700a4-7ee3-4074-a04f-f96976b5a5b7) and [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d(%3f%3d.(.)*).*)(%3f%3c%3d((%3f(8)%5e(%3f(7)!)(%3f%3c-7%3e.)*)(%3f%3c%3d(%3f%3c2%3eC%7cC(%3f(1)!)(%5cn%7c(%3f%3c-1%3e.))*)%3f)C(%3f%3d(%3f%3c2%3eC%7c(%5cn%7c(%3f%3c-1%3e.))*(%3f(1)!)C)%3f)(()(%3f(6)!)%7c.*%5cn(.)*()(%3f(8)!)))%3f)%7b2%7d_(%3f%3d(%3f%3c2%3e((%3f(10)!)()%7c(%3f(11)!)()(.)*%5cn.*)(%3f%3c%3d(%3f%3c2%3eC%7cC(%3f(1)!)(%5cn%7c(%3f%3c-1%3e.))*)%3f)C(%3f%3d(%3f%3c2%3eC%7c(%5cn%7c(%3f%3c-1%3e.))*(%3f(1)!)C)%3f)(%3f(11)(%3f%3c-12%3e.)*(%3f(12)!)%24))%3f)%7b2%7d(%3f%3c-2%3e)%3f(%3f(2)!)&i=_______C_________%0d%0a___C__C_____C____%0d%0a____C____C__C____%0d%0a_CC___CC______CC_%0d%0a___C_____________%0d%0a&o=m). The regex works both with and without trailing newline, and uses `_` in place of `.`. (Apparently, RegexStorm occasionally has problems if there is no trailing newline, but RegexHero seems to handle either case fine.)

There is a horrible amount of duplication in the regex, and I have a couple of ideas for shortening it significantly... I'll give that a try later and then add an explanation. In the meantime, let me know if you can find any inputs which yield a wrong result.

Answer (score 7):

## J, <s>75 73</s> 68 bytes

```
(+.0j1^i.4)(+:@](LF,@:,.~'*.C'{~>.)(2=f)+.[f]*f=.[:+/|.!.0)'C'&=;._2
```

Uses the format in the question, using `.`/`*`/`C` for space/usable space/chest, respectively.

Edit: fixes a small bug (I accidentally used a torus instead of properly treating the surrounding as empty space).

### Explanation

```
## Preparation
              'C'&=;._2  NB. Map ./C to 0/1, turn into matrix
(+.0j1^i.4)              NB. Compute offsets to shift into each direction
                         NB. (i.e. [[_1 0], [1 0], [0 _1], [0 1]] in any order)


## "Part B"
(2=f)+.[f]*f=.[:+/|.!.0  NB. This part computes a matrix that is 1 for cells that
                         NB. cannot contain a chest:
              [:+/|.!.0  NB. Sum of shifts: shift in each of the four cardinal
                         NB. directions (using the array above) and then sum up.
           f=.           NB. Define this function as `f`; we'll use it some more.
         ]*              NB. Multiply by the "is chest" matrix: this isolates
                         NB. double-chests.
       [f                NB. Sum of shifts--1 for double-chest neighbours.
(2=f)                    NB. Isolate cells with two neighbouring chest.
     +.                  NB. Boolean or--either two neighbouring chests or next
                         NB. to a double-chest.

## Wrap up the result
(+:@] (fmt >.) PartB)    NB. Maximum of the array from the above and twice the "is
 +:@]      >.  PartB     NB. chest" matrix--this is 0,1,2 for '*', '.' or chest,
                         NB. respectively.

## Output formatting
LF,@:,.~'*.C'{~          NB. Format output...
        '*.C'{~          NB. Map 0,1,2 to '*.C' by using the value as index
LF   ,.~                 NB. Append line feed at end of each line
  ,@:                    NB. Ravel into one line
```

Answer (score 4):

## C,193

2 unnecesary newlines for clarity. Changes with respect to ungolfed code include: characters as ascii codes instead of character literals; rearrangement of v=0,strlen, and  strchr to save characters (strchr is the ugliest, as it means that a calculation that would otherwise be performed once only, is performed 5 times per cell!)

C functions do not accept strings as arguments or return them as values, so the best I can do is the following: `q` is a pointer to the input string. The function modifies the string and when the function returns the output is found in the original string.

```
g(char*q){int v,j,w,l;
int f(p,d){int s=0,i=w=strchr(q,10)-q+1,r;for(;w/i;i-=i-1?w-1:2)r=p+i,r>-1&r<l&&q[r]==67&&++s&&d&&f(r,0);v|=s>d;}
for(j=l=strlen(q);j--;f(j,1),46-q[j]||v||(q[j]=42))v=0;}
```

To summarize the rules:

a blank square (that does not contain C or newline) can be converted if it has max 1 neighbour with a C

...AND that neighbour has no neighbours with a C.

The function g contains a function f that recurses down from depth 1 to depth 0. With only 2 levels of recursion, a simple `f(r,0)` recursive call will do, there is no need for `f(r,d-1)`!

**Ungolfed code in test program**

Input test string is hardcoded. `gets` and `scanf` will not accept an input string with newlines in it; they chop it into pieces at each newline.

```
char n[]=".......C..\n...C..C...\n.........C\n.CC...CC..\n..........";

g(char*q){

  int v,j,w,l;

  int f(p,d){                    //p=cell to be checked,d=recursion depth
    int s=0,i=w,r;               //sum of C's found so far=0, i=width
    for(;w/i;i-=i-1?w-1:2)       //For i in   w,1,-1,-w   = down,right,left,up
      r=p+i,                     //r=cell adjacent to p
      r>-1&r<l&&q[r]=='C'&&++s   //If r not out of bounds and equal to C, increment s...
        &&d&&f(r,0);             //...and if recursion depth not yet at zero, try again one level deeper. 
    v|=s>d;                      //If the local s exceeds d, set global v to true to indicate invalid.
  }

  w=strchr(q,10)-q+1;            //width equals index of first newline + 1                   
  l=strlen(q);                   //length of whole string;
  for(j=l;j--;)                  //for l-1 .. 0 
    v=0,                         //clear v
    f(j,1),                      //and scan to see if it should be set
    '.'-q[j]||v||(q[j]='*');     //if the character is a '.' and v is not invalid, change to '*'
}

main(){
  g(n);
  puts(n);
}
```

**Output based on question example**

```
******.C**
***C**C.**
*..***..*C
.CC.*.CC.*
*..***..**
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 124 <s>129</s>

Using characters 0 (*), 6 (C), 7(.)

```
F=s=>[for(c of(d=[o=~s.search('\n'),-o,1,i=-1],s))
   d.map(j=>t-=s[i+j]==6&&~d.some(k=>s[i+j+k]==6),t=i++)|c<7|t>i&&c
].join('')
```

**Ungolfed** and explained

```
F=s=>
{
  o=~s.search('\n') // offset to prev row (~ is shorter than +1 and sign does not matter)
  d=[o,-o,1,-1] // array of offset to 4 neighbors
  i=-1
  result = '' // in golfed code, use array comprehension to build the result into an array, then join it
  for (c of s) // scan each char
  {
    t = i++ // set a starting value in t and increment current position in i
    d.forEach(j => // for each near cell, offset in j
    {         
      if (s[i+j]==6) // if cell contains a Chest, must increment t
      {  
        // In golfed code "~some(...)" will be -1(false) or -2(true), using decrement instead of increment
        if (d.some(k=>s[i+j+k]==6)) // look for another Cheast in the neighbor's neighbors
        {
          // more than one chest, position invalid
          t += 2
        }
        else
        {
          t += 1
        }
      }
    })
    if (c < 7 // current cell is not blank
        || t > i) // or t incremented more than once, position invalid
    {
       result += c // curent cell value, unchanged
    }
    else
    {
       result += 0 // mark a valid position 
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

**Test** In Firefox/FireBug console

```
a='\
7777777677\n\
7776776777\n\
7777777776\n\
7667776677\n\
7777777777\n';

console.log(F(a))
```

*Output*

```
0000007600
0006006700
0770007706
7667076670
0770007700
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 66

The regexp matching chest conflicts ended up on the long side, so no competing with CJam this time.

```
#!perl -p0
/.
/;$"=".{@-}";s%0%s/\G0/2/r!~/2((.$")?2(.$")?|2$"|$"2)2/s*1%eg
```

Uses 0 and 2 for empty and chest spaces on the input, 1 to mark the spots on the output.

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/cVbss2).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 - 281 bytes

```py
f=lambda x,y:sum(m[y][x-1:x+2])+m[y-1][x]+m[y+1][x]
m=[];o=''
try:
 while 1:m+=[map(int,'0%s0'%raw_input())]
except:a=len(m[0]);l=len(m);m+=[[0]*a]
for y in range(l*2):
 for x in range(1,a-1):
    if y<l:m[y][x]*=f(x,y)
    else:o+=`2if m[y-l][x]else +(f(x,y-l)<5)`
 if y>=l:print o;o=''
```

*(Lines 8 and 9 are intended with a single tab character, which SE converts to 4 spaces. Every line in this program has either 0 or 1 bytes of leading whitespace.)*

Input: `0` for no chest, `2` for chest
Ouput: `0` for no chest, `2` for existing chest, `1` for possible new chest

---

God, this is horrible. I must be seriously out of practice. I threw every trick I know at it and it came out... well, it came out as 281 bytes, losing to every answer except the one in *regex*, haha. I honestly feel like I golfed it kinda well, so I'm guessing that my algorithm was just less than ideal.

**Ungolfed:**

```py
def f(x,y):
    """Given x,y coords of the board, return the sum of that point and all
    adjacent points.
    """
    return (sum(board[y][x-1:x+2]) # (x-1,y) + (x,y) + (x+1,y)
            + board[y-1][x]
            + board[y+1][x])
board=[]
output=''
try:
    while True:
        row = '0%s0' % raw_input() # line from stdin with a leading and trailing 0
        board.append(map(int, row)) # convert to list of ints
except:
    pass # exception is thrown when stdin is empty

board_width = len(board[0])
board_height = len(board)

board.append([0]*board_width) # new row of all 0s

for y in xrange(board_height*2):
    # board_height multiplied by 2 so we can use this loop to simulate two
    for x in xrange(1,board_width-1):
        if y < board_height: # "first loop"
            board[y][x] *= f(x,y) # multiply everything on the board by itself + sum
                                  # of neighbours
                                  # empty cells (0) stay 0 no matter what
                                  # lone chests (2 surrounded by 0) become 2*2==4
                                  # double chests (2 touching another 2) are weird:
                                  # - one chest becomes 2*(2+2)==8
                                  # - the other chest becomes 2*(2+8)==20
        else: # "second loop"
            if board[y - board_height][x] != 0:
                output += '2' # anything not equal to 0 is an existing chest
            else:
                valid = f(x, y - board_height) < 5 # if the sum of neighbours > 4, the
                                                   # current cell is either beside a
                                                   # double chest or more than one
                                                   # single chest
                output += '01'[valid]
    if y >= board_height: # only print during the "second loop"
        print output
        output=''
```